# Magento2 Override 2 classes in single plugin di.xml

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, mini-cart

I am making a custom module for displaying attributes in Minicart and cart page and I have changed two core classes

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php

vendor/magento/module-checkout/model/DefaultConfigProvider.php
```

and some views files

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.phtml
```

Module is working fine but as I have changed core classes so its not good because when upgrade it will lost.I want to override both classes

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php

vendor/magento/module-checkout/model/DefaultConfigProvider.php
```

In custom module but **I don't have any idea that we can do this.If we try to do this by plugin** so can I override two classes in single **di.xml**?

Or what will be best approach to achieve this.
Please help me anybody.

Answer (score 1):

For core files you have to use your module's di.xml for override.

for ex:

`/app/code/{your Vendor name}/{your Module name}/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="{your Vendor name}\{your Module name}\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" type="{your Vendor name}\{your Module name}\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" />
</config>
```

Now create file **DefaultItem.php** in your custom module as per di path

```
app/code/{your Vendor name}/{your Module name}/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php

<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace {your Vendor name}\{your Module name}\CustomerData;

/**
 * Default item
 */
class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
{
    enter code here....
}
```

use same for **DefaultConfigProvider.php**

And for overwrite view file, Create **Magento_Checkout** directory in your theme directory and add your code in overrited file 
for ex :

`app/design/frontend/Magento/{YourTheme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

Comment: Hi Aasim,
I have tried same way but after overriding files I am getting empty cart when adding product to cart.

Comment: not able to override Vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php
     <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" type="Vendor\Module\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" />
and in code file is located place of app/code/Vendor/module/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php
namespace Vendor\Customcart\Model;
class DefaultConfigProvider extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider
{
    private function getTotalsData()
    {
  $logger->info("Test code");  //not able to reach here
 }
}